# Menu driven program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to complete my menu driven program; however, I can't get this code to function properly. the goal is to get information from my previous code then get the evaluated output here. It keeps asking to execute my previous function before the menu pops up. get_list is the previous function that gets the list of numbers from the user.

previous code

```
def get_list(score_list=None):
if score_list is None:
    score_list = []
n = int(input('How many scores do you want to enter? '))
for n in range(1, n + 1):
    score = float(input('Enter score #{}: '.format(n)))
    while True:
        if 0 > score or score > 100:
            print('Invalid score entered!!\n', 'Score should be a value between 0 and 100')
            score = float(input('Enter score #{}: '.format(n)))
            continue

        else:
            score_list.append(score)
            break
return score_list
```

pass

problem code
def evaluate_list():

```
    score_list = get_list()
    lowest_score = min(score_list)
    score_list.remove(lowest_score)
    score_average = sum(score_list) / len(score_list)

    if 90 < score_average <= 100:
        grade = 'A'
    elif 70 < score_average <= 80:
        grade = 'B'
    elif 40 < score_average <= 60:
        grade = 'C'
    elif score_average > 20 and score_average >= 40:
        grade = 'D'
    else:
        grade = 'F'

    print('----------Results--------------')
    print('Lowest Score : ', lowest_score)
    print('Modified List: ', score_list)
    print('score Average: ', f'{score_average:.2f}')
    print('Grade        : ', grade)


evaluate_list()
```

Comment: What is `get_list`?

Comment: Please fix the indentation.  [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Why have you neglected 81 to 90 (inclusive), 61 to 70 (inclusive), and so on?

Comment: What do you mean by "It keeps asking to execute my previous function before the menu pops up?

Comment: A minor issue is the `>=40` condition, but you write *"It keeps asking to execute my previous function before the menu pops up"*: this is not something we can see from the code you have given us. There is no loop there, so nothing "keeps asking". Please include enough code to reproduce the issue. Moreover, have you applied any debugging techniques (set stops, inspect variables, step through the code, ...etc)?